# Google Compute Engine >>unexpected (unknown) user making continues request to our website (home page)

Tags: linux, security, google-compute-engine

we have hosted our website (server, Linux Debian ) on Google Compute Engine instance, the problem is that, from last 5 days, someone (unknown ) unexpected user making continually request to our website,(home page)  that's why, our back-end server load is increasing, and unexpected data download is increasing. we saw our server log, continually request is coming to our server.

for that we tried to reach request point from where these continues request is making, but we are not able to find. Kindly suggest us, how to stop that continuous requests.

Is there any service to protect our compute engine instance from unknown users?

Please find below snippet is out server log.same request making continually

```
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 150.102 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 217.073 ms - 343825
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 25.765 ms - 11966
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 60.548 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 106.435 ms - 343827
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 27.907 ms - 11965
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 54.128 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 86.679 ms - 343824
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 33.595 ms - 11966
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 87.592 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 127.591 ms - 343824
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 29.016 ms - 11966
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 69.063 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 113.770 ms - 343826
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 20.781 ms - 11965
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 53.646 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
GET /api/beta/article/new/home/assets?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 82.988 ms - 343825
GET /api/beta/article/dr-n-n-khanna-senior-interventional-cardiologist-apollo-hospital-new-delhi-coronary-artery-disease-compounded-by-peripheral-vascular-disease?limit=1&skip=0&compact=&category=&event=&key=6ZzQ52peX5XqUx3t824670wv8jIaf1B4 200 5.652 ms - 2967
GET /api/beta/article/dr-n-n-khanna-senior-interventional-cardiologist-apollo-hospital-new-delhi-coronary-artery-disease-compounded-by-peripheral-vascular-disease/related?limit=4&skip=0&compact=1&category=&event=&key=6ZzQ52peX5XqUx3t824670wv8jIaf1B4 200 14.006 ms - 6601
GET /api/beta/article?key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg&top_category=true 200 28.000 ms - 11966
GET /api/beta/home/new/image?&key=7xOyNH554tY83cBN7Ktpw3s1y68ql6Eg 200 76.620 ms - 69746
sjhfjhf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always block traffic from certain IPs by setting up [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls).

This approach is quite naive and in case you're under real DDoS attack - consider using a real DDoS mitigation solution like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/), etc.